# cassandra primary key design

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am using datastax enterprise 4.5. Is there any disadvantage of defining a composite partition key than only a single column partition key in terms of any performance? What if one column of composite partition has high cardinality but the other coulmn of the composite has low cardinality?

Answer (score 3):

A composite key is used to increase the cardinality of your partitions. For example a key like `PRIMARY KEY ((x,y))` with 5 values of x and 10 values of y will end up creating 50 different partitions. This is usefuls if you need to distribute your data more but is unnecessary if you have a single variable with high enough cardinality.

A more realistic example might be creating a composite key of `PRIMARY KEY ((Gender, ZipCode), age, userid)`. If you used only Gender as the Partition key you would end up with only 2 partitions to store your data! Adding zipcode allows for a total of all 99999 zipcodes or (zip+4 to get even more) while still allowing you to segregate your data by gender. This would be ideal for looking demographic information by location or something like that.

Basically the rule of thumb is that you want a large number of partitions to avoid hotspots in your cluster and composite keys allow an easy way of increasing the number of partitions by combining the cardinality of your fields.